# Запись полученной переменной из запроса в файл используя PHP

Tags: php, request

У меня стоит задача сделать запись полученного результата в файл, выглядит это примерно так:

> 1) Запрос из приложения несущий в себе некое число
>
> 2) Запрос принимает php скрипт
>
> 3) Полученное число записывается в конец текстового файла на сервере

Как это можно реализовать, может у кого уже есть наработки?

Comment: Поисковый запрос "php запись в файл" вам ничего не выдал?

Comment: @u_mulder Как сделать запись переменной используя html я знаю. Вопрос в том как реализовать это через POST запрос

Comment: $i = $_POST['var'];

Comment: И всем __конкретно__ вопрос?

Answer (score 1):

```
file_put_contents(куда, что."\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);//LOCK_EX - блок файла, можешь убрать
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделал это так:

```
<?php
$score = $_GET['score'];
$fd = fopen("HighScore", 'a');
fwrite($fd, $score . "\n");
fclose($fd);
?>
```